# Symfony2 - Access repository from random class

Tags: symfony

I plan on doing this differently once I get more knowledge, but for now I am trying to get something working.

I have everything set up how it should be.  Once an alert is added to the database, I needed to perform some actions on that alert.  So I done an EventListener, which basically calls the function I need in my random class

```
<?php

namespace Nick\AlertBundle\EventListener;

use Doctrine\ORM\Event\LifecycleEventArgs;
use Nick\AlertBundle\Entity\AvailabilityAlert;
use Nick\AlertBundle\Service\ApiService;

class AvailabilityAlertListener
{

    public function postPersist(LifecycleEventArgs $args)
    {
        $entity = $args->getEntity();
        if ($entity instanceof AvailabilityAlert) {
            $api = new ApiService();
            $api->addFlightsAction($entity);
        }
    }
}
```

Now the class ApiService doesnt really fit into my design at the moment, its just a random class for now.  I pass it my $entity so I can perform some actions on it.

One of the actions I need to do involves the entitys custom repository class.  So my class ApiService looks like so

```
<?php

namespace Nick\AlertBundle\Service;

class ApiService
{
    public function executeTerminalCommand($entity){

        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $worldspanCommand = $em->getRepository("NickAlertBundle:AvailabilityAlert")->getSpecificAlert($entity->getId());
    }
}
```

So in the EventListender, I am calling the above function and passing it the entity.  This function should call a function in my custom respository class.  With the above, I am getting the error

> Attempted to call method getDoctrine on class
>   Nick\AlertBundle\Service\UapiService (500 Internal Server Error)

How would I go about getting this working?

Thanks

Comment: first of all: ` $api->addFlightsAction($entity);` and `public function executeTerminalCommand($entity){ ... }` has different signatures;-)

Comment: Sorry, that was my mistake, I was cutting down the class so I dont post all the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two solutions for this

### First solution (recommend)

Make `ApiService` class a symfony2 service and inject <s>`EntityManager`</s> `ServiceContainer` (to avoid `ServiceCircularReferenceException`) (either [construct injection](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/dependency_injection/types.html#constructor-injection) or [setter injection](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/dependency_injection/types.html#setter-injection)) so you can use it directly. To do that you also need to inject this new service to your event listener.

#### You can do this as follows (Take a look to Edit also)

<s>1) Make your `ApiService` class a service</s>

```
your_bundle_name.api_service:
        class: Path\To\Your\Api\Service\Class
        arguments: [@doctrine.orm.entity_manager] #i.e.: constructor injection
```

2) Modify your `ApiService` class

```
<?php

namespace Nick\AlertBundle\Service;

use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager; //!IMPORTANT
class ApiService
{
    protected $em:

    public function __construct(EntityManager $em) 
    {
        $this->em = $em;
    }

    public function executeTerminalCommand($entity)
    {
        $worldspanCommand = $this->em->getRepository("NickAlertBundle:AvailabilityAlert")->getSpecificAlert($entity->getId());
    }
}
```

This could lead to `ServiceCircularReferenceException` My solution is to change point 1) and 2) as follows

1) Make your `ApiService` class a service

```
your_bundle_name.api_service:
        class: Path\To\Your\Api\Service\Class
        arguments: [@service_container]
```

2) Modify your `ApiService` class

```
<?php

namespace Nick\AlertBundle\Service;

use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerInterface as Container; //!IMPORTANT
class ApiService
{
    protected $sc;

    public function __construct(Container $sc) 
    {
        $this->sc = $sc;
    }

    public function executeTerminalCommand($entity)
    { 
        $em = $this->sc->get('doctrine.orm.entity_manager');
        $worldspanCommand = $em->getRepository("NickAlertBundle:AvailabilityAlert")->getSpecificAlert($entity->getId());
    }
}
```

3) Modify your event listener service to accept service container as a parameter onto instantiation

```
your_listner_name:
    class: Path\To\Your\Listener\Class
    arguments: [@your_bundle_name.api_service]
    tags:
        - { name: doctrine.event_listener, event: postPersist }
```

4) Modify your event listener class

```
<?php

namespace Nick\AlertBundle\EventListener;

use Doctrine\ORM\Event\LifecycleEventArgs;
use Nick\AlertBundle\Entity\AvailabilityAlert;
use Nick\AlertBundle\Service\ApiService;

class AvailabilityAlertListener
{
    protected $api_service;

    public function __construct(ApiService $api_service)
    {
        $this->api_service = $api_service;
    }

    public function postPersist(LifecycleEventArgs $args)
    {
        $entity = $args->getEntity();
        if ($entity instanceof AvailabilityAlert) {
            $this->api_service->addFlightsAction($entity);
        }
    }
}
```

### Second solution

Inject service container directly into your listener and let your `ApiService` class accept an entity manager as parameter

#### You can do this as follows

1) Modify your `ApiService` class in order to make it accept entity manager

```
<?php

namespace Nick\AlertBundle\Service;

use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager; //!IMPORTANT
class ApiService
{
    protected $em:

    public function __construct(EntityManager $em) 
    {
        $this->em = $em;
    }

    public function executeTerminalCommand($entity)
    {
        $worldspanCommand = $this->em->getRepository("NickAlertBundle:AvailabilityAlert")->getSpecificAlert($entity->getId());
    }
}
```

2) Modify your event listener class as follows

```
<?php

namespace Nick\AlertBundle\EventListener;

use Doctrine\ORM\Event\LifecycleEventArgs;
use Nick\AlertBundle\Entity\AvailabilityAlert;
use Nick\AlertBundle\Service\ApiService;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerInterface as Container;


class AvailabilityAlertListener
{
    public function postPersist(LifecycleEventArgs $args)
    {
        $entity = $args->getEntity();
        if ($entity instanceof AvailabilityAlert) {
            $entity_manager = $args->getEntityManager();
            $api = new ApiService($entity_manager);
            $api->addFlightsAction($entity);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the fantastic explanation.  I was going through the docs and didnt really understand services, but seeing it in your code I can see exactly what is going on.  I did get one error though which I am now trying to resolve;                                                                             Circular reference detected for service "doctrine.dbal.default_connection", path: "doctrine.dbal.default_connection".

Comment: @NickPrice: what solution did you follow?

Comment: I was following the first one.  Thats the way I was intending to do in the future, because I know this should be a service.

Comment: @NickPrice: could you paste full error stack or stacktrace (pastebin please)

Comment: @NickPrice: take a look to my update, I've not tried but if I understood correctly, this should works

Comment: I have tested it out, and I get a different error this time (and where I have that new use statement in ApiService, it is greyed out meaning it is not being used) http://pastebin.com/AhPiUsNA

Comment: @NickPrice i had a typo into ApiService constructor, see update

Comment: This one seems to give a bigger circular reference error http://pastebin.com/HtT3QAFd

Comment: @NickPrice i've modified ApiService again. If this will not work I don't have any other ideas without testing it directly

Comment: Thats perfect, the last update seems to work perfectly from what I have seen so far.  Thank you very much for the help.